# Lift roots of a polynomial from $\mathbb{F}_p$ to $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory, hensels-lemma

I was trying to prove a counterexample to Hasse's principle. To do this, I was trying to prove that the equation $x^4-17=2y^2$ has no solutions on $\mathbb{Q}$ but has solutions in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for every prime $p$.

I was able to prove that the equation has no solutions on $\mathbb{Q}$, but I was not able to do the second part. What I've done was to prove (using Riemman-Hurwitz) that  $x^4-17=2y^2$ defines an elliptic curve and thus Hasse's theorem gives us that the curve is non empty over $\mathbb{F}_p$ (i.e. the equation has at least one solution over $\mathbb{F}_p$). The cases $p=2,17$ are special, but these are easily checked.

From here I know that I have to use Hensel's lemma to lift the solution to $\mathbb{Q}_p$. This is the Hensel's lemma I was trying to use (maybe it is not the correct form of Hensel's lemma):

**Let $(K,|\cdot|)$ be a complete valuation field, $f\in R[X]$ and $a_0\in R$ such that $|f(a_0)|<|f'(a_0)|^2$, where $R=\lbrace x\in K\mid|x|\leq 1\rbrace$. Then, there exists a unique $a\in R$ such that $f(a)=0$ and $a-a_0\in\mathcal{M}$, where $\mathcal{M}=\lbrace x\in K\mid|x|< 1\rbrace$.**

I'm not sure how to use this, since the theorem involves a polynomial in $x$, but I'm working with a polynomial in $x$ and $y$. Also, I'm not sure how to relate roots in $\mathbb{F}_p$ and roots in $\mathbb{Q}_p$. I know that the residual field of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is $\mathbb{F}_p$ (i.e. $R/\mathcal{M}\cong\mathbb{F}_p$) but I'm not sure how this relates with Hensel's lemma.

Any hints or help will be thanked.

Comment: Show that an $\mathbf F_p$-solution can be lifted by either fixing $y$ and finding a suitable $x$ or vice versa.  The equation $x^4 - y^2 - 17 = 0$ is a polynomial in both $x$ and $y$, so it becomes a polynomial in one variable by fixing a value of the other variable. See the answer by KConrad to the MO question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134352/the-modular-arithmetic-contradiction-trick-for-diophantine-equations?rq=1 for an analogue of this for the equation $y^2 = x^3 + k$.

Comment: $3^4-17=8^2$, no?

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry I missed a 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me just fill in the details of KCd's comment for completeness. First assume $p\neq 2,17$, and let $(a+p\mathbb{Z},b+p\mathbb{Z})$ be a root of our polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_p$. Then at least one of $a$ and $b$ is non-zero mod $p$; otherwise $17$ would be zero mod $p$, a contradiction. So we have two cases.

First suppose $a\notin p\mathbb{Z}$. Consider the polynomial $g(x)=x^4-(17+2b^2)$. Then $g(a)\equiv 0$ mod $p$ and $g'(a)=4a\not\equiv 0$ mod $p$, so by Hensel's lemma there is a root $a'$ of $g$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Now $(a',b)$ is a $\mathbb{Q}_p$-rational point of our curve.

Now suppose $b\notin p\mathbb{Z}$. Then consider the polynomial $h(y)=2y^2+(17-a^4)$. Then $h(b)\equiv 0$ mod $p$ and $h'(b)=4b\not\equiv 0$ mod $p$, so by Hensel's lemma there is a root $b'$ of $g$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Now $(a,b')$ is a $\mathbb{Q}_p$-rational point of our curve. Either way, we are done.

---

For the case $p=17$, you can use almost an identical argument as above; we just need to find an *non-zero* $\mathbb{F}_{17}$-rational point of the polynomial to work. (Why does this suffice?) For example, take $(1+17\mathbb{Z},3+17\mathbb{Z})$. Finally, for the case $p=2$, it would suffice to show that $17$ is a fourth power in $\mathbb{Q}_2$, and by Hensel's lemma it suffices for this to show that $17$ is a fourth power mod $2^5$. (Why?) But $3^4=81$ is congruent to $17$ mod $2^5$, as needed.

Comment: Nice, thank you :). One question, are you sure that Hasse's theorem tells us that $p-1-2\sqrt{p}>0$ and not $p+1-2\sqrt{p}>0$?

Comment: @Marcos my pleasure, happy it helped! and oops, I think you're right; I misremembered the Hasse bound! I've corrected it now :)

Comment: Don't worry. What I dont get is the last bit (the $p=2$ case). I got that the general argument fails, because in the general case the derivatives also vanishes since $4=0$. The reasoning for taking $2^5$ and no other power of $2$ is because taking $y=2^2$ it it easy to find a solution for $x^4=17$? Why we can do the same for $2^3$? since $y=2$ and $x=1$ works too and it is easier to find.

Comment: Ohh, I think I got it... Is it because we need $|f'(a)|^2\neq0$ and since we have a factor of $4$ the lowest possible power of $2$ for $|f'(a)|^2$ to be not $0$ is $2^5$?

Comment: @Marcos indeed – letting $f(x)=x^4-17$, we want to have $|f(a)|<|f'(a)|^2$. now, $f'(a)=4a$, so $|f'(a)|^2=|4|^2|a|^2=|a|^2/2^4$. so, if $|a|=1$, we want $|f(a)|<2^{-4}$; this occurs if and only if we have $f(a)$ congruent to $0$ mod $2^5$. does that make sense?

Comment: Indeed, thanks.